# Mako: def composition (at render time) not evaluating properly

Tags: python, template-engine, mako, function, metalanguage

In the process of understanding Mako (template engine for Python), I started playing with defs constructs.

One thing I attempted to do was producing a general "if" statement (say, a JavaScript one) out of def calls. Here's the text:

```
<%def name="if_statement(x)">if (${x})</%def>
<%def name="sample_condition()">3 == 3</%def>

${if_statement(sample_condition())}
```

The output is not the expected `if(3 == 3)`, but `3 == 3if()`, just like `if_statement`'s argument was evaluated before any other content of the def and rendered at the front.

Is this the expected behavior? And if yes, why?
Also, how could I achieve what I was trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a desired behavior due to [buffering](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html?highlight=capture#buffering), but you can easily get it working as you wanted with use of built-in `capture()` function. Here's the working example:

```
<%def name="if_statement(x)">if (${x})</%def>
<%def name="sample_condition()">3 == 3</%def>

${if_statement(capture(sample_condition))}
```

Result is `if (3 == 3)`.